# Ubuntu 15.10: Cannot resume from hibernate

Tags: boot, grub2, suspend, hibernate

I just updated to Ubuntu 15.10. Hibernation works fine on 15.04. Now it's not.
Here are some information:

```
quang@ubuntu:~$ cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system>                             <mount point>      <type>  <options>                                  <dump>  <pass>

UUID=bef5e506-c800-469f-a7d6-d518e1102328   /                  ext4    noatime,data=writeback,errors=remount-ro   0       1

UUID=9c7da40c-89d7-4eb6-aab7-bd0067dfa753   /home              ext4    noatime,data=writeback,defaults            0       2

UUID=a3fa91b7-4262-4253-a24e-5ee2b221f524   /var               ext4    noatime,data=writeback,defaults            0       2

UUID=D8C0-A1BC                              /boot/efi          vfat    defaults                                   0       0

UUID=4cea5ee8-3322-48c6-b05e-2e90854f088e   none               swap    sw                                         0       0

quang@ubuntu:~$ cat /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume 
RESUME=UUID=4cea5ee8-3322-48c6-b05e-2e90854f088e
```

It works if I put resume=UID=4cea5ee8-3322-48c6-b05e-2e90854f088e in linux param in grub.cfg thought but not without it. How to get it to work like before without touching grub.

Comment: Ummm... put in the parameter then... it's kind of required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Pilot6 suggested, I post the answer here.
I have to append

```
resume=UUID=4cea5ee8-3322-48c6-b05e-2e90854f088e
```

to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in `/etc/default/grub` then update GRUB using

```
sudo update-grub
```

Answer (score 0):

After you entered `RESUME=UUID=4cea5ee8-3322-48c6-b05e-2e90854f088e` to `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume` you need to run

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: I will try it and give the result later. Thanks.

Comment: I am sorry to say that it does not work. Anyway, I have to append resume=UUID=4cea5ee8-3322-48c6-b05e-2e90854f088e to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT in /etc/default/grub to make it work and I am happy with it now. Thank for your help anyway.

Comment: @QuangNgô This worked! Thank you. I wonder if this should be reported as a bug.

Comment: In some cases only this option help. It is weird.

Comment: @QuangNgô Will you convert it to an answer, or I can add it to mine as an option.